# Spring boot web mvc application Servlet context set problem

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator, servletcontextlistener

I have a multi tenant spring mvc application which i want to convert to spring boot web mvc application. I have changed the related dependencies and the project compiles good and also the entities are generated. But in runtime getting the below exception

`2023-08-27 13:16:47.640  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] c.o.h.AppApplication                     : Starting AppApplication on LAPTOP-POCB5T7C with PID 22872 (C:\Users\ASUS\IdeaProjects\ZorgFlex\app\hcs-web\target\classes started by ASUS in C:\Users\ASUS\IdeaProjects\ZorgFlex)
2023-08-27 13:16:47.648  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] c.o.h.AppApplication                     : The following profiles are active: dev
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.5.9/groovy-2.5.9.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2023-08-27 13:16:47.859  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.r.ChangeableUrls                 : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\ASUS.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
2023-08-27 13:16:47.860  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.r.ChangeableUrls                 : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\ASUS.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.11\jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.11/jaxb-core.jar
2023-08-27 13:16:47.860  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.r.ChangeableUrls                 : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\ASUS.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-core\2.2.11\jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/ASUS/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/2.2.11/jaxb-api.jar
2023-08-27 13:16:47.860  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-08-27 13:16:47.860  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-08-27 13:16:50.184  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-08-27 13:16:50.799  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 607ms. Found 153 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-08-27 13:16:51.574  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] c.o.h.c.HCSCoreContext                   : Application properties loaded
2023-08-27 13:16:51.578  WARN 22872 --- [  restartedMain] c.o.h.c.ApplicationPropertyResource      : properties loaded :(resource='application.properties')
2023-08-27 13:16:51.578  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] c.o.h.c.ApplicationPropertyResource      : application properties loaded
2023-08-27 13:16:51.580  WARN 22872 --- [  restartedMain] c.o.h.c.ApplicationPropertyResource      : Could not find properties (file='C:\Users\ASUS.hcs\application.properties'), ignoring this set of properties.
2023-08-27 13:16:51.876  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'HCSServiceContext' of type [com.orsbv.hcs.config.HCSServiceContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eddd1207] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-08-27 13:16:51.913  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'mailConfiguration' of type [com.orsbv.hcs.config.SMTPConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-08-27 13:16:51.914  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'com.orsbv.hcs.config.HCSCoreContext' of type [com.orsbv.hcs.config.HCSCoreContext] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-08-27 13:16:51.917  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'dataSourceConfiguration' of type [com.orsbv.hcs.config.DataSourceConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-08-27 13:16:51.917  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'HCSRepositoryContext' of type [com.orsbv.hcs.config.HCSRepositoryContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$81f4c60] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-08-27 13:16:52.263  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-08-27 13:16:52.428  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-08-27 13:16:52.650  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.j.i.u.LogHelper                      : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-08-27 13:16:52.714  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.Version                              : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2023-08-27 13:16:52.835  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.a.c.Version                          : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2023-08-27 13:16:53.400  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.d.Dialect                            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2023-08-27 13:16:55.317  WARN 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.o.cache                              : HHH90001006: Missing cache[com.orsbv.hcs.model.financier.Financier] was created on-the-fly. The created cache will use a provider-specific default configuration: make sure you defined one. You can disable this warning by setting 'hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy' to 'create'.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.405  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.financier.Financier' created in EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.417  WARN 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.o.cache                              : HHH90001006: Missing cache[com.orsbv.hcs.model.Dome] was created on-the-fly. The created cache will use a provider-specific default configuration: make sure you defined one. You can disable this warning by setting 'hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy' to 'create'.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.421  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.Dome' created in EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.422  WARN 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.o.cache                              : HHH90001006: Missing cache[com.orsbv.hcs.model.Company] was created on-the-fly. The created cache will use a provider-specific default configuration: make sure you defined one. You can disable this warning by setting 'hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy' to 'create'.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.425  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.Company' created in EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.427  WARN 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.o.cache                              : HHH90001006: Missing cache[com.orsbv.hcs.model.Province] was created on-the-fly. The created cache will use a provider-specific default configuration: make sure you defined one. You can disable this warning by setting 'hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy' to 'create'.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.430  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.Province' created in EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.431  WARN 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.o.cache                              : HHH90001006: Missing cache[com.orsbv.hcs.model.multitenancy.UserTenant] was created on-the-fly. The created cache will use a provider-specific default configuration: make sure you defined one. You can disable this warning by setting 'hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy' to 'create'.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.435  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.multitenancy.UserTenant' created in EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.435  WARN 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.o.cache                              : HHH90001006: Missing cache[com.orsbv.hcs.model.CompanySettings] was created on-the-fly. The created cache will use a provider-specific default configuration: make sure you defined one. You can disable this warning by setting 'hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy' to 'create'.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.439  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.CompanySettings' created in EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.440  WARN 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.o.cache                              : HHH90001006: Missing cache[com.orsbv.hcs.model.CareTeam] was created on-the-fly. The created cache will use a provider-specific default configuration: make sure you defined one. You can disable this warning by setting 'hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy' to 'create'.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.443  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.CareTeam' created in EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.444  WARN 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.o.cache                              : HHH90001006: Missing cache[com.orsbv.hcs.model.Person] was created on-the-fly. The created cache will use a provider-specific default configuration: make sure you defined one. You can disable this warning by setting 'hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy' to 'create'.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.447  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.Person' created in EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.447  WARN 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.o.cache                              : HHH90001006: Missing cache[com.orsbv.hcs.model.multitenancy.Tenant] was created on-the-fly. The created cache will use a provider-specific default configuration: make sure you defined one. You can disable this warning by setting 'hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy' to 'create'.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.452  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.multitenancy.Tenant' created in EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.452  WARN 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.o.cache                              : HHH90001006: Missing cache[com.orsbv.hcs.model.function.Function] was created on-the-fly. The created cache will use a provider-specific default configuration: make sure you defined one. You can disable this warning by setting 'hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy' to 'create'.
2023-08-27 13:16:55.455  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.function.Function' created in EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:16:57.345  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.o.c.access                           : HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$MultiTenantConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@75d8d529] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
2023-08-27 13:16:59.982  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-08-27 13:17:00.052  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-08-27 13:17:04.068  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor           : Initializing ExecutorService 'clientInboundChannelExecutor'
2023-08-27 13:17:04.076  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor           : Initializing ExecutorService 'clientOutboundChannelExecutor'
2023-08-27 13:17:04.154  WARN 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.d.f.TemplateRenderer                 : HHH000174: Function template anticipated 4 arguments, but 1 arguments encountered
Aug 27, 2023 1:17:04 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {http://nigw.soap.services}PatientPortTypeService from class services.soap.nigw.patient.PatientPortType
Aug 27, 2023 1:17:06 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {http://services.cibg.nl/ExternalUser}PublicV4SoapService from class com.orsbv.hcs.external.model.PublicV4Soap
2023-08-27 13:17:07.605  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'hcs_custom_cache' created in EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:17:07.606  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.j.Eh107CacheManager                  : Registering Ehcache MBean javax.cache:type=CacheStatistics,CacheManager=file./C./Users/ASUS/IdeaProjects/ZorgFlex/app/hcs-repository/target/classes/hcs_ehcache.xml,Cache=hcs_custom_cache
Aug 27, 2023 1:17:08 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {http://nigw.soap.services}OrganizationPortTypeService from class services.soap.nigw.organization.OrganizationPortType
Aug 27, 2023 1:17:08 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {http://nigw.soap.services}EmployeePortTypeService from class services.soap.nigw.employee.EmployeePortType
Aug 27, 2023 1:17:08 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {http://nigw.soap.services}PatientArchivePortTypeService from class services.soap.nigw.archivePatient.PatientArchivePortType
2023-08-27 13:17:08.918  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain       : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/resend-token'], []
2023-08-27 13:17:08.918  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain       : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/robots.txt'], []
2023-08-27 13:17:08.918  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain       : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/demo-user'], []
2023-08-27 13:17:08.980  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain       : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5ac2b26b, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7cddbd72, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2663f88c, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@1d063466, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7e20d283, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@3637847c, org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter@54f51586, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@16890040, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@417b8d58, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter@3419810a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@50dcc92b, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4763316a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@431ee67c, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@5a369062, com.orsbv.hcs.security.MultiTenantSwitchUserFilter@2aa84978]
2023-08-27 13:17:09.238  WARN 22872 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
2023-08-27 13:17:09.247  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'hcs_custom_cache' removed from EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:17:09.256  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor           : Shutting down ExecutorService 'clientOutboundChannelExecutor'
2023-08-27 13:17:09.256  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor           : Shutting down ExecutorService 'clientInboundChannelExecutor'
2023-08-27 13:17:09.290  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-08-27 13:17:09.291  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.Dome' removed from EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:17:09.291  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.Person' removed from EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:17:09.292  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.CompanySettings' removed from EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:17:09.292  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.CareTeam' removed from EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:17:09.292  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.multitenancy.Tenant' removed from EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:17:09.292  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.financier.Financier' removed from EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:17:09.292  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.Company' removed from EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:17:09.293  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.Province' removed from EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:17:09.293  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.multitenancy.UserTenant' removed from EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:17:09.293  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.c.EhcacheManager                     : Cache 'com.orsbv.hcs.model.function.Function' removed from EhcacheManager.
2023-08-27 13:17:09.298  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-08-27 13:17:09.310  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-08-27 13:17:09.318  INFO 22872 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-08-27 13:17:09.320 ERROR 22872 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at com.orsbv.hcs.AppApplication.main(AppApplication.java:32) [classes/:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:534) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
... 23 more`

This is my Servlet contect configuration class.

```
`@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.orsbv.hcs.controller", "com.orsbv.hcs.advice", "com.orsbv.hcs.validator"})
@Import({MethodSecurityConfig.class, HCSSpringDataWebConfiguration.class, HCSWebSocketConfig.class,
        HCSWebSocketSecurityConfig.class})
public class HCSServletContext extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(JS_ROUTE + "/**")
                .addResourceLocations(PATH + "/js/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());

        registry.addResourceHandler(CSS_ROUTE + "/**")
                .addResourceLocations(PATH + "/css/", PATH + "/css/writer/bootstrap/css/",
                        PATH + "/css/writer/font-awesome/css/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());

        registry.addResourceHandler(IMAGE_ROUTE + "/**")
                .addResourceLocations(PATH + "/images/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());

    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        super.addInterceptors(registry);
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
        registry.addInterceptor(tenantIdentifierInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName(LANGUAGE_PARAM);
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public TenantIdentifierInterceptor tenantIdentifierInterceptor() {
        return new TenantIdentifierInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        factory.setMessageInterpolator(new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(new PlatformResourceBundleLocator("messages", null, true)));
        return factory;
    }
}`
```